# failing to add an exit to this loop

Tags: bash, scripts

Found this interesting script that draws snow inside your terminal, however....
I would like to have an option to type 'q' at any time to exit the loop.
This is what I have;

```
 

 LINES=$(tput lines)
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)
 
declare -A snowflakes
declare -A lastflakes
 
clear

function move_flake() {    

i="$1"
 
if [ "${snowflakes[$i]}" = "" ] || [ "${snowflakes[$i]}" = "$LINES" ]; then
snowflakes[$i]=0
else
if [ "${lastflakes[$i]}" != "" ]; then
printf "\033[%s;%sH \033[1;1H " ${lastflakes[$i]} $i
fi
fi
 
printf "\033[%s;%sH*\033[1;1H" ${snowflakes[$i]} $i
 
lastflakes[$i]=${snowflakes[$i]}
snowflakes[$i]=$((${snowflakes[$i]}+1))
}
 
while :
do
    
i=$(($RANDOM % $COLUMNS))
 
move_flake $i

for x in "${!lastflakes[@]}"
do
move_flake "$x"
done
 
sleep 0.1
done
```

this is that I have tried to add ;

```
echo "Type 'q' to exit out"
while read -n1 -r -p "want to exit the script?"
do
    if [[ $REPLY == q ]];
    then
        break;
    else
        #whatever
    fi
done
```

added it inside the function, but only ask for the 'q' at the very beginning.
then attempted to add the actual script inside the quit loop and only draws an snow flake then ask again if I want to exit....
Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Why don't you just use Ctrl+C to exit?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this in the shell `bash`: Replace the `sleep` command with a `read` command, that has a timeout, and let `while` check for your `'q'`. See

```
help read | less
```

Here is my version of your snow-show,

```
#!/bin/bash

LINES=$(tput lines)
COLUMNS=$(tput cols)

declare -A snowflakes
declare -A lastflakes
 
clear

function move_flake() {    

i="$1"
 
if [ "${snowflakes[$i]}" = "" ] || [ "${snowflakes[$i]}" = "$LINES" ]; then
snowflakes[$i]=0
else
if [ "${lastflakes[$i]}" != "" ]; then
printf "\033[%s;%sH \033[1;1H " ${lastflakes[$i]} $i
fi
fi
 
printf "\033[%s;%sH*\033[1;1H" ${snowflakes[$i]} $i
 
lastflakes[$i]=${snowflakes[$i]}
snowflakes[$i]=$((${snowflakes[$i]}+1))
}
 
while [ "$ans" != "q" ]
do
    
 i=$(($RANDOM % $COLUMNS))
 
 move_flake $i

 for x in "${!lastflakes[@]}"
 do
  move_flake "$x"
 done
 read -sn 1 -t 0.1 ans
done
```

Comment: Ha! I didn't know bash's `read` had a timeout option. Nice!

Comment: @terdon, Yes, it is a nice option. I have used it several times in my scripts :-)

Comment: @terdon I'll have to read up more on the `read` command too :P

Comment: FANTASTIC!!!
Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: You are welcome @Erniemenendez :-) I enjoyed the snowing screen, used to to prepare for the winter ... made it fully fullscreen with `xterm`: `xterm -fullscreen -e bash -c 'sleep 1;./snow'` from the directory where I put the script. If you let the snow melt on the ground, it will be a simple but nice screensaver.